# How to close CSS menu when clicking on links with JS?

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox, navigation

So I made a pure CSS menu and everything looks how I want it, except for when clicking the links. In my single page layout clicking the links navigates to a section of the page, but upon clicking the link, it just smooth scrolls to the section and the menu remains visible. I have read multiple similar questions and none of the solutions have worked for me. I would prefer to use JavaScript and no jQuery.

My website is still in working progress; check it out to really see what happens on mobile size https://www.itsalaam.com/

Here is my code:

```css
/* NAVIGATION */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), transparent);
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* transition: background .2s ease-out; */
}
.header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}
.header ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.header .logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.header .logo img {
    width: 50px;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
.header .menu {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    max-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon {
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*menu-icon serves as the parent element of the span nav-icon the is nested within. so the span is the child element*/
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon {
    /*creates the middle bar of the nav-icon*/
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after,
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    background: #fff;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    top: 5px;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
    top: -5px;
}
.header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
    /* the ~ selects the next sibling  */
    max-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
    /*because the max height was set to 0 on the .menu once the menu-btn is checked, the for attribute must match the id of the input checkbox. so when you click the label it targets the check box, which was set to display none.*/
}
/* the X for closing */
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
    background: transparent;
}
/*middle line disappears*/
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 0;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="/img/globeWireframe.png" alt="salaam" /></a>
      <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" />
      <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: If I understood, you want that the menu itself disappears once a user click on a link, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript:
1. Get the checkbox to use it later.
2. Get all links in menu.
3. Add an event listener for each link to uncheck the checkbox on click, knowing that menu is displayen only when the checkbox is checked.

```js
// Run once everything is loaded
window.onload = function() {
    // Get the checkbox
    let chk = document.getElementById('menu-btn');
    // Get all menu links
    let menuLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li a');
    // Loop on links
    menuLinks.forEach(function(item) {
        // Add event listener to each links
        item.addEventListener('click', function() {
            // When link is clicked, uncheck the checkbox to hide menu
            chk.checked=false;
        });
    });
}
```

```css
/* NAVIGATION */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), transparent);
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* transition: background .2s ease-out; */
}
.header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    font-size: 1.7rem;
}
.header ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.header .logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.header .logo img {
    width: 50px;
    transition: width .5s ease;
}
.header .menu {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    max-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon {
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*menu-icon serves as the parent element of the span nav-icon the is nested within. so the span is the child element*/
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon {
    /*creates the middle bar of the nav-icon*/
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after,
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    background: #fff;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    top: 5px;
}
.header .menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
    top: -5px;
}
.header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
    /* the ~ selects the next sibling  */
    max-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 99;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
    /*because the max height was set to 0 on the .menu once the menu-btn is checked, the for attribute must match the id of the input checkbox. so when you click the label it targets the check box, which was set to display none.*/
}
/* the X for closing */
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon {
    background: transparent;
}
/*middle line disappears*/
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 0;
}
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .nav-icon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
      <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="/img/globeWireframe.png" alt="salaam" /></a>
      <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn" />
      <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="nav-icon"></span></label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
```

Comment: So I tried to implement it into my live site and it doesn't respond the same way.

Comment: Actually it turns out I just needed to change my browser cache config on firefox. It works now, thanks again.